# A word to refer to the cases of something

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Consider:

> There are more than 10 fields for a word including the following **items/fields**:

Should I repeat *following fields* or  I can say *following items*?

What are other words like *items*.

Comment: Just omit it altogether.

Comment: I would leave it off entirely:  _There are more than 10 fields for a word, including the following:_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat "fields", or use a different word like "instances", but no additional word is necessary. Simply write:

> There are more than 10 fields for a word including the following:

The word following can mean "what follows or comes next", so the sentence means:

> There are more than 10 fields for a word including *what comes next*: